# iOS: Seeding an app with items from a plist

Tags: ios, nsarray, plist, appdelegate

I'm trying to populate or seed my app with certain items, using the next method, which is called in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
    -(void)seedItems {
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![ud boolForKey:@"MUserDefaultsSeedItems"]) {
        // Load seed items
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"seed" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSArray *seedItems = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 0; i < [seedItems count]; i++) {
            NSDictionary *seedItem = [items objectAtIndex:i];
            MShoppingItem *shoppingItem = [MShoppingItem createShoppingItemWithName:[seedItem objectForKey:@"name"] andPrice:[[seedItem objectForKey:@"price"] floatValue]];
            [items addObject:shoppingItem];
        }

        // Items path
        NSString *itemsPath = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"items.plist"];

        // Write to file
        if ([NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:items toFile:itemsPath]) {
            [ud setBool:YES forKey:@"MUserDefaultsSeedItems"];
        }
    }
}
```

The file `seed.plist`has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Naranjas</string>
        <key>price</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Peras</string>
        <key>price</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Manzanas</string>
        <key>price</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

The problem is that that when doing `NSArray *seedItems = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];`, it says that the array contains 3 objects, but they're `Out of scope` and `Summary Unavailable`.

Any idea, please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have the `filePath`, check that it exists using `NSFileManager`. If it doesn't exist, check that the file is properly added to Xcode and that it is set as part of your app target so that it appears in the 'Copy Bundle Resources' build phase. You can check the target membership by selecting the seed file in Xcode and viewing the 'Target Membership' in the Utilities inspector.

Your update to the question indicates that the array is loaded, but that in the debugger it is listed as not available. That indicates that the array has been released (because it isn't used anymore). That indicates a typo. Looking at the code more closely, I see:

```
NSDictionary *seedItem = [items objectAtIndex:i];
```

Which should probably be:

```
NSDictionary *seedItem = [seedItems objectAtIndex:i];
```

I guess you were previously seeing a crash?

Comment: well the file exists and I also checked the target membership and all the Copy Bundle Resources and everything's fine

Comment: thanks a lot, it was exactly that problem. I got confused with the names. Cheers!